# inconsistent outcomes when using magrittr and negation operator

Tags: r, logical-operators, magrittr

```
> v <- c(1,2,NA,5)
> is.na(v)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> !is.na(v)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> 
> !is.na(v) %>% all()
[1] TRUE
> all(!is.na(v))
[1] FALSE
> (!is.na(v)) %>% all()
[1] FALSE
```

In the absence of parenthesis, `%>%` is applying all() to `is.na(v)` and then applying `!` operator. Why does it have such order of operation here, and for what other functions/operators should I be weary of this?

Answer (score 2):

magrittr provides a [set of operators](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/magrittr.pdf) that work better with its chaining. So, you can use

```
not(is.na(v)) %>% all()
```

Advice is

> ...special attention is advised when using non-magrittr operators in a pipe-chain
>   (+, -, $, etc.), as operator precedence will impact how the chain is evaluated. In general it is
>   advised to use the aliases provided by magrittr.